# Coding in Maple

Tags: sequences-and-series, maple

I am trying to animate a sequence of functions in Maple and I am stuck on how to do so.
This is what I have so far

```
animate(seq(plot(sin(n*x)/n, x = -Pi .. Pi), n = 1 .. 50));
```

but it keep coming up as an error for the range. I have to do this in Maple. Any ideas?

Comment: **General debugging help:** First, try just the command `plot(sin(n*x)/n, x = -Pi .. Pi)`.  Then we know if the error lies there.  If that runs without problem, then wrap the `seq` command, and, if that works, the `animate` command.  **Specific debugging help:** I forget if Maple cares about spaces.  Try removing the spaces between the endpoints of the ranges and the `..`s.

Comment: it shouldn't be that because I can display it just fine

Comment: I did that though and still there is an error

Comment: I take that back, there is a warning in the plot command

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: This is not an appropriate forum for questions on just Maple coding and syntax. Better would be stackoverflow or mapleprimes.com. This forum is intended for questions about mathematics (which may involve a program like maple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so What I should do is add the command insequence=true command in at the end of my code here:

display(seq(plot(sin(n*x)/n, x = -Pi .. Pi), n = 1 .. 50)). So it looks like

display(seq(plot(sin(n*x)/n, x = -Pi .. Pi), n = 1 .. 50), insequence = true);

Then just hit play.

Comment: Notice that you also changed the outermost command from `animate` to `display` (or `plots:-display`) in order to get your workaround with the `insequence` option. That works, as does Carl's corrected syntax for the actual `animate` command.

Answer (score 4):

You have the wrong syntax for **animate**. It takes three required arguments. The first is a plotting procedure, the second is a list of arguments to that procedure, and the third is the name and range of the animation parameter. So, it should be

```
animate(plot, [sin(n*x)/n, x= -Pi..Pi], n= 1..50);
```